# QT SLOT: Pointer to Member Function error

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, pointer-to-member, slot

I'm currently working on a Qt project and I have some troubles with SLOTs.
I want to pass a pointer to member function as an argument of a SLOT. To do this, I declared the SLOT in my class but when I do so, I get MOC error.
I don't know if what I want to achieve is even possible.

An exemple of syntax for a class named MainFrame:

```
void slotAnswerReceived (QString answer, void (MainFrame::*ptr)(QString));
```

I don't have any connect anywhere, nothing using that function, and the only error I have is on this line above.

Thank you everyone for the help. I cannot find any solution on the web (but I found this article explaining [SIGNAL and SLOT in depth](http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html) if someone is interested).

Comment: Just a little question : why do you want to pass a pointer as argument ?

Comment: What error do you get? Possible, you forgot to call Q_DECLARE_METATYPE / qRegisterMetatype for your function pointer type?

Comment: [debug/moc_MainFrame.cpp] Error 1.
Don't heard about Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (I'll look). I know that I can put the declaration of this function in public and it works, but I can't use it as a SLOT because of that error.
I'm using a QTcpServer and when I receive an answer I also got that pointer which gives me the next function to call.

Comment: I tried to put 
    qRegisterMetaType<MainFrame>("MainFrame");
but it says that compilation error: "QMainWindow is private".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Declare a typedef for that pointer-to-member type.
2. Declare and register the metatype for that typedef.
3. Only use the typedef - remember that moc uses string comparison to determine type equality, it has no C++ type expression parser.

An example follows. At the time `a.exec()` is called, there are two `QMetaCallEvent` events in the event queue. The first one is to `c.callSlot`, the second one is to `a.quit`. They are executed in order. Recall that a queued call (whether due to `invokeMethod` or due to a signal activation) results in posting of a `QMetaCallEvent` for each receiver.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaObject>

class Class : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   typedef void (Class::*Method)(const QString &);
private:
   void method(const QString & text) { qDebug() << text; }
   Q_SLOT void callSlot(const QString & text, Class::Method method) {
      (this->*method)(text);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void callSignal(const QString & text, Class::Method method);
public:
   Class() {
      connect(this, SIGNAL(callSignal(QString,Class::Method)),
              SLOT(callSlot(QString,Class::Method)),
              Qt::QueuedConnection);
      emit callSignal("Hello", &Class::method);
   }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Class::Method)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   qRegisterMetaType<Class::Method>();
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   Class c;
   QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&a, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```